# Start LibreOffice in presentation mode on boot raspberry pi

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I wrote a tiny bit of scrip, as bash, that starts up LibreOffice Impress presentation in fullscreen, and then runs in for 5 minutes, then kills it and starts it again (in case of file replacement).

The script works as intended. But I cannot get it to run on startup or logon.

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ : ]
do
        libreoffice --norestore --show /mnt/Presentation/Presentation.odp & echo $!
        sleep 5m
        kill $!
done
```

But now my issue is, that I cannot get the script to start up on boot.
I am running on the latest version of Raspberry Pi OS (Previously known as Raspbian).

I did try the init.d, crontab, systemd, .bashrc, as .desktop and rc.local, all of which doesn't really start up the script.

I did add chmod +x on the script file, to make it executeable.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, using "autostart".

It was something, I did try earlier. But aparantly there is an obsolete version of it.

Anyways, if anyone comes across this, and cannot get a bash script to run on start up here is the answer:

Go edit with you favorite `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`. It is the operating system path for startup. If you want it to be user specific, use `/home/$USERNAMEHERE/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`.

Then add this command to the bottom of the file:

> @lxterminal -e /home/pi/Desktop/Script.sh

Then you should have the file to boot on startup. It worked like a charm for me.

Also remember to do `chmod +x` on the file, to make it executeable of course.